# Ubuntu 10.10, taskbar

Tags: linux, taskbar

I launched system monitor to kill one program, which didn't responded on any mouse clicks, etc.
But i occasionally killed another process. 
so, taskbar was killed. (it was in the bottom of the screen, in the top all is good)
reboot didnt help o_O.
Now I use Alt-Tab and alt-controll-arrows to switch between programs and desktops (it works).
How to launch taskbar again? its very strange that reboot didnt help me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i found it.
Right-click on panel, add-to-panel.
I looked through the list 5 times, and then saw, that i can add switcher of desktops and list of programs there.
But its interesting, why reboot didnt help?